# SendMessage to a window Handle

Tags: c#, c++, sendmessage

I am try to use sendmessage to pass the message from my c++ application to c#

my c++ code is like this

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

 COPYDATASTRUCT cpd;
 cpd.dwData = 0;    
 LPCWSTR strDataToSend = L"http://google.com";;

     cpd.cbData = (wcslen(strDataToSend) + 1) * 2;
     cpd.lpData = (PVOID)strDataToSend; 
 SendMessage((HWND)0x0020073C,5555,0,(LPARAM)&cpd);


return 0;
}
```

i tried with  SendMessageW also i hard coded the handle which is correct i am hetting the call back but not getting any data

my C# application is like this

```
    public struct COPYDATASTRUCT
    {
        public IntPtr dwData;
        public int cbData;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string lpData;
    }


    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        // Listen for operating system messages.

        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            // The WM_ACTIVATEAPP message occurs when the application
            // becomes the active application or becomes inactive.
            case 5555:

                COPYDATASTRUCT mystr = new COPYDATASTRUCT();
                Type mytype = mystr.GetType();
                mystr = (COPYDATASTRUCT)m.GetLParam(mytype);
                MessageBox.Show ( mystr.cbData.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show(mystr.lpData);
                break;
             }
             base.WndProc(ref m);
           }
```

i am getting the Messagebox blank......
i tried with out using COPYDATASTRUCT  only my passing string plz can any one help me..
Thanks in Advance

---

```
  int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
  {

  COPYDATASTRUCT cpd;
  cpd.dwData = 0;    
  LPCWSTR strDataToSend = L"http://google.com";;

   cpd.cbData = (wcslen(strDataToSend) + 1) * 2;
   cpd.lpData = (PVOID)strDataToSend; 
   SendMessage((HWND)0x0020073C,WM_COPYDATA,0,(LPARAM)&cpd);


 return 0;
}
```

C# code

```
public struct COPYDATASTRUCT
{
    public IntPtr dwData;
    public int cbData;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string lpData;
}
 public const int WM_COPYDATA = 0x4A;


protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    // Listen for operating system messages.

    switch (m.Msg)
    {
        // The WM_ACTIVATEAPP message occurs when the application
        // becomes the active application or becomes inactive.
        case WM_COPYDATA:

            COPYDATASTRUCT mystr = new COPYDATASTRUCT();
            Type mytype = mystr.GetType();
            mystr = (COPYDATASTRUCT)m.GetLParam(mytype);
            MessageBox.Show ( mystr.cbData.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(mystr.lpData);
            break;
         }
         base.WndProc(ref m);
       }
```

Comment: The [suggested `COPYDATASTRUCT`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/COPYDATASTRUCT.html) seems to look different than yours. (e.g. `LayoutKind.Sequential` attribute).

Comment: The comment refers to `WM_ACTIVATEAPP`, the `COPYDATASTRUCT` suggests `WM_COPYDATA`, but 5555 is neither of those.

Comment: yes you are right.... thank u v much..... i did't think about it.... thank's hvd

Answer (score 0):

I modified source code a bit and it's working. From C++ code I used this call

`SendMessage((HWND)0x0020073C,WM_COPYDATA,0,(LPARAM)&cpd);`

In C# application I used following

```
public const int WM_COPYDATA = 0x004A;
```

and `COPYDATASTRUCT` is

```
 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct COPYDATASTRUCT
        {
            public IntPtr dwData;
            public int cbData;
            public IntPtr lpData;
        }
```

and message handler is modified like this

```
  case WM_COPYDATA:        

                    COPYDATASTRUCT mystr = new COPYDATASTRUCT();             

                    mystr = (COPYDATASTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(COPYDATASTRUCT));

                    if (mystr.cbData > 0)
                    {
                        byte[] data = new byte[mystr.cbData];
                        Marshal.Copy(mystr.lpData, data, 0, mystr.cbData);
                        Encoding unicodeStr = Encoding.Unicode;
                        char[] myString = unicodeStr.GetChars(data);
                        string returnText = new string(myString);
                        MessageBox.Show("Text is " + returnText);
                    }


                    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is some basic IPC (interprocess communication).

This is not a problem for C#, but for C++ it is.

Perhaps some basic COM will help you. It is quite easy and you no longer have to use SendMessage, Window handles and that like

[Introduction to COM](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/633/Introduction-to-COM-What-It-Is-and-How-to-Use-It)

[Introduction to COM Part 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/901/Introduction-to-COM-Part-II-Behind-the-Scenes-of-a)