# How can I port this Interprocess-communication code from c++ to c#?

Tags: c#

hoping that anybody can help me:

```
    void irsend_qtask(t_irsend *x)
{
        LRESULT copyDataResult;
        HWND pOtherWnd = FindWindow(NULL, "WinLirc");
        if (pOtherWnd)
        {
            COPYDATASTRUCT cpd;
            cpd.dwData = 0;
            cpd.cbData = strlen(x->s_string) + 1;
            cpd.lpData = (void*)x->s_string;
            copyDataResult = SendMessage(pOtherWnd, WM_COPYDATA, (WPARAM)(HINSTANCE)GetModuleHandle(NULL), (LPARAM)&cpd);
            //post("irsend: I send: %s", x->s_string);
            outlet_bang(x->p_outlet); //Send a Bang
        }
        else
        {
            post("irsend: Error! WinLIRC not running?"); //Error
        }
}
```

There should be only one data structure to another program.

**I have a working code now:**

```
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct COPYDATASTRUCT
        {
            public IntPtr dwData;    // Any value the sender chooses.  Perhaps its main window handle?
            public int cbData;       // The count of bytes in the message.
            public IntPtr lpData;    // The address of the message.
        }

        const int WM_COPYDATA = 0x004A;

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
        public struct MYSTRUCT
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 127)]
            public string mystring;
        }

        MYSTRUCT mystruct;
// Allocate a pointer to an arbitrary structure on the global heap.
        public static IntPtr IntPtrAlloc<T>(T param)
        {
            IntPtr retval = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(param));
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(param, retval, false);
            return retval;
        }

        // Free a pointer to an arbitrary structure from the global heap.
        public static void IntPtrFree(ref IntPtr preAllocated)
        {
            if (IntPtr.Zero == preAllocated)
                throw (new NullReferenceException("Go Home"));
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(preAllocated);
            preAllocated = IntPtr.Zero;
        }
...

   private void irsend()
        {
            mystruct.mystring = "LED-Controller-#1 RED1 0";
            IntPtr hWnd = (IntPtr)FindWindow(null,"WinLirc");
            if (hWnd!=IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                IntPtr buffer = IntPtrAlloc(mystruct);
                COPYDATASTRUCT cpd = new COPYDATASTRUCT();
                cpd.dwData = IntPtr.Zero;
                cpd.cbData = (Marshal.SizeOf(mystruct)+1);
                cpd.lpData = buffer;
                IntPtr copyDataBuff = IntPtrAlloc(cpd);
                SendMessage(hWnd, WM_COPYDATA, GetModuleHandle(null), copyDataBuff);
                IntPtrFree(ref copyDataBuff);
                IntPtrFree(ref buffer);
            }
       }
```

I just do not understand a few things, for example the "unmanaged structures"
I should write something here: "Where power is mindless, the mind is powerless!"

Comment: Related: [SendMessage to a window Handle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909453/sendmessage-to-a-window-handle)

Comment: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/COPYDATASTRUCT.html